# Conditional select list show related terms in single vocabulary

Tags: drupal-7, conditional-statements, content-type

I have a list of my products with various status steps:

- Product 1 steps: Preparations, Printing, *Cutting* ...
- Product 2 Steps: Preparations, Printing, *Covering* ...

I created a new content type (Order), and two vocabulary:

- Products vocabulary: list of all products
- Products steps vocabulary: List of all products steps

and create two select list (Terms reference) for each

And i need to: when select product from first select list, second select list (products steps) show **only related terms (steps) of product**!

How can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

I think this can help you: https://www.drupal.org/project/hierarchical_select

Best,
C

Answer (score 0):

I 'd suggest to create a two levels taxonomy vocabulary  where you can create the relationship between steps and products. For every step you should assign a parent product. The outcome will be a tree structure vocabulary like the following

```
-Product 1
 -Printing
 -Cutting
 -Covering
-Product 2
 -Printing
 -Covering
 .....
 ect
```

Then you can use the hierarchical select module that Claudiu Chirilov also suggested